# How do I get SSIS to use my dtsConfig file?

Tags: visual-studio, ssis

All the information I can find talks about going to Package Configurations but I can't find it anywhere or anything else that references config files.

I've looked at MS documentation and various tutorials and they all say the same thing, go to left click on the Control Flow canvas and then go to the SSIS menu and select Package Configurations...
OR
Right click on the canvas and select Package Configurations...

None of these exist. I'm in VS 2017.

Where is package configurations? Or whatever the relevant setting is to make my dtsx file use my dtsconfig file.

Answer (score 2):

It does exist, but not readily available when the project is using the Project Deployment Model (default beginning with 2012). The expectation is that with the project deployment model, you're going to deploy to the SSISDB which has its own structure for holding configuration data.

To use dtsConfig, you need to right click on the project and select Convert to Package deployment model. If you're using Package/Project parameters, project connection managers and Execute Package Tasks with a project reference, those are incompatible with the Package Deployment Model.

Otherwise, you can directly configure a deployed project in the SSISDB i.e. ConnectionString = ABC

Or, you can create an Environment variable (collection really) of properties packages can use for configuration purposes. Then, when you go to configure the project/packages, you can say ConnectionString = EnvironmentA.connString_ABC

### Not readily available

Pedantic answer is yes, it's there but when the project deployment model is deployed to the SSISDB, *where* should it find the .dtsconfig file? All the other resources it needs are bundled into the .ispac and stored in the SSISDB but now you'll have this config file sitting somewhere on the file system, subject to different backup and restore polices, with ACL to configure to ensure the account(s) executing packages can read the file, etc.

[image: Package Properties, Configurations, click ellipses]

Comment: I don't think the client is set up to receive packages using the Project Deployment Model. I wasn't aware that a change had been made (I don't do a lot of work with SSIS). Following your instructions I was able to enable package configurations. Hopefully that works. Thanks!